# Kotlin: certain value in list only once

Tags: kotlin

Lets say I have a list with values and I want to check if there is a certain value in this list only once.

Whats the most fast solution to that?

Lets check if the list contains only one time 1
[0, 0, 0, 1] true
[1, 0, 0, 1] false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `count`:

```
val element = 1 // the element we care about
val onesInData = data.count { it == element}
```

You can also create a generic function that works with any type, not just `Int`:

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.checkExactlyOnce(element: T): Boolean {
    return count { it == element} == 1
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution! I totally forgot about count !

Comment: You could get better performance, strictly speaking, e.g. with Miha_x64's answer, but only at the cost of code clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun <T> List<T>.containsOnce(value: T): Boolean {
    val idx = data.indexOf(value)
    return idx != -1 && data.lastIndexOf(value) == idx
}
```